# NodeJs Perform Operation on Each returned MySql Result Object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

Im using NodeJs to fetch data from mysql database, from the result object/array i want to perform specific action (call web service) with data returned from mysql. unfortunately whenever i iterate through mysql result and call web service only one object from the mysql resultset is called against web service. Here are my codes.

```
    app.get('/blt', function(req, res){

        var sql = "SELECT dest, amt FROM dit WHERE dest != 'DEST' && amt != 'AMT'";
        pool.getConnection(function(err, conn){
            if(err){
                console.log("MYSQL Connection Error: "+err);
            }
            else{
                conn.query(sql, function(err2, result){
                    if(err2){
                        console.log("Some error: "+err2);
                    }
                    else{
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                        Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
                            let result_ = result[key];      
                            let sn = Math.floor((Math.random() * 900000000) + 100000000);  
                            let dacc_ = result_.dest;
                            console.log(dacc_);




                                let blDetail = {
                                    "BalDto": {
                                        "Src": "XXXXXX",
                                        "Code": 1,
                                        "Amt": 10,
                                        "Dac": dacc_, //Variable from mysql resultset
                                        "Cmt": "Ok",
                                        "SN": sn
                                    }
                                };


                            soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
                                client.addSoapHeader(AuthHeader);
                                client.BalTransfer(blDetail, function(err, result) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.log(err.body); 
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("done");
                                    }
                                });
                            });  
                    }
                    );



                    }
                    conn.release(function(errs){
                        if(errs){
                            console.log(errs)
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
});
```

I tried to use async but still i got the same results, only one of the returned mysql result set is sent to web service.

I want all the result set to be sent to webservice one by one, Kindly Help

Answer (score 0):

You're literally iterating through your response from MySQL, which is a list of something, then you're making the soap call on every single one of them.

What you need to do is this:

1. Check the soap client and what they accept.
2. See if it accepts an array of your BalDto Objects
3. Utilize const listOfBalDtos = object.keys(result).map(); to do your transformation
4. Make the request:

   ```
    soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
     client.addSoapHeader(AuthHeader);
     client.BalTransfer(listOfBalDtos);
    });
   ```

try something like this.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not support array